# Do any of the common Linux utilities allow changing to arbitrary UID given CAP_SETUID?

Tags: bash, debian, shell, chroot, container

I sometimes have the need to change my UID to arbitrary value when testing user namespace functionality.

Currently, I do something like:

```
useradd -u <uid> testuser
su testuser
userdel testuser
```

I first need add the user in order to `su`, since `su` doesn't accept an arbitrary UID, but only a valid username found in `/etc/passwd`?

Do any of the common Linux utilities allow changing to arbitrary UID given `CAP_SETUID`?

NB: I know I could compile a small `setuid(2)` application, but it's cumbersome to transfer it into e.g. containers everytime I want to test user namespace functionality.

Comment: At the end you mention "containers". Why can't you just leave a test user inside the container for this purpose?  Why do you need to tear it down every time?  I ask because this seems like a bad idea generally.

Comment: @PhilipCouling - it's because I work as a penetration tester, primarily focusing on cloud, so I have some methods of working that don't reflect normal usage

Comment: It's better to make this sort of this explicit to avoid tripping up future readers.  What's your requirement: to get a process running without matching user entry, or to run as a different user without the overhead of setup / tear down?

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear exactly what you're trying to achieve.  From your question you might be:

- Attempting to execute something as a different user for testing without the overhead of creating that user every time
- Attempting to run a process as a user that doesn't exist (with not matching entry in `/etc/passwd` or more precisely with `getent passwd`)
- Attempting to test the behaviour of `CAP_SETUID`

If either of the first two then you could just create an executable with `setuid` and `setgid` bits set and set the executable user and group to an arbitary number.  You don't even need to compile your own executable, just copy an existing one.

As root:

```bsh
mkdir test_dir
# Secure the directory to prevent tampering by other users
chmod go-rx test_dir 
cd test_dir

cp $(which bash) .

# arbitrary user 1997  group 1998
chown 1997:1998 ./bash
chmod ug+s ./bash
chmod go+rx ./bash

# Run touch as an arbitrary user
./bash -p -c `touch /tmp/test_file`

# Check the result
ls -lh /tmp/test_file
-rw-r----- 1 1997 1998 0 Jan 11 08:22 /tmp/test_file
```

---

Additionally python (a scripting programming language) is available on many platforms.  You could write a very short python script to run something after calling setuid and setgid:

eg uid.py:

```py
import os
import sys
import subprocess

# Set uid and gid
os.setuid(int(sys.argv[1]))
os.setgid(int(sys.argv[2]))

# Run the given command, passing in remaining arguments.
subprocess.run(*sys.argv[3:])
```

Then, with `CAP_SETUID` given to python you could:

```
python setuid.py 1997 1998 touch /tmp/test_file
```

This will have the same effect of running `touch` with uid 1997 and gid 1998.

Note that python scripts do not need to be created as files they can be passed inline:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16938013/453851

Comment: @user414777 I wrote it without testing, but the principle is sound enough.

Comment: @PhilipCouling — thank you. Indeed, I’m interested in the first two  scenarios, since I need to chance my UID from inside a container to match a UID outside the container, without an entry for that user present in the container’s `/etc/passwd`. While you show me how to achieve that using custom methods, I was really hoping for a solution like `su <uid>` in order to login as that UID. I see there’s no standard Linux utility supporting that.

Answer (score -1):

> Do any of the common Linux utilities allow changing to arbitrary `UID` given `CAP_SETUID`?

No, they don't.

> I know I could compile a small `setuid(2)` application, but it's cumbersome to transfer it into e.g. containers everytime I want to test user namespace functionality.

If you plan to do your testing framework in bash, *everything* will be "cumbersome", to say the least.